# set-jaxb-validation-event-handler config is not working

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws, apache-tomee, openejb

My client is sending an incorrect message (we are migrating from Weblogic10 to Tomee 8.0.15. The first one was more permissive with incorrect xml's acording with de wsdl), so I have been trying to avoid the error

> Unmarshalling Error: element unexpeted (URI:"", local:"foo"). Expected elements are &lt ...

So I concluded that adding the following config in openjb-jar.xml (as appear [here](https://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/cxf-schema-validation-with-tomee/))

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openejb-jar>
    <ejb-deployment ejb-name="MyService">
        <properties>
            cxf.jaxws.properties = MyServiceProperties
        </properties>
    </ejb-deployment>
```

And this resources.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <Service id="MyServiceProperties" class-name="java.util.Properties">
        set-jaxb-validation-event-handler = false
        schema-validation-enabled = false
    </Service>
</resources>
```

or this annotation in the definition of my WebService class

```java
@EndpointProperties({ 
    @EndpointProperty(key = "set-jaxb-validation-event-handler", value = "false")
})

@WebService(name="MyService",targetNamespace="http://my.namespace/MyService" )
public class MyService {
...
}
```

should avoid the problem.

I'm deploying this services in Tomee 8.0.15, using JAX-WS and Apache CXF.

Any clue why this is not working?
I expect that the error of unmarshalling not appear any more.